# Release React-Native App Crashing Randomly

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I implement an app with the help of react-native with the following version

```
{
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.0.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    **"react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.5",**
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "file:react-native-calendars",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "file:react-native-device-info",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.4",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-material-buttons": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-medl-splash": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-star-rating-view": "0.0.12",
    "react-native-swipeable-rating": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-native-wheel-picker-android": "^2.0.5",
    **"react-navigation": "^2.12.1",**
    "tipsi-stripe": "^7.4.0",
    "xdate": "^0.8.2"
  }
```

The whole application is working fine but sometimes it crashed with the following log.

```
Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001f41b20dc 0x1f418f000 + 143580
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f422b094 0x1f4229000 + 8340
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001f410aea8 0x1f40b0000 + 372392
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f37d7788 0x1f37d6000 + 6024
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f37d7934 0x1f37d6000 + 6452
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001f37eee00 0x1f37e9000 + 24064
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f37e3838 0x1f37d6000 + 55352
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f37e38c4 0x1f37d6000 + 55492
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001f40547e8 0x1f3ff4000 + 395240
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001f3ffd324 0x1f3ff4000 + 37668
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001f3ffde40 0x1f3ff4000 + 40512
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001f40064ac 0x1f3ff4000 + 74924
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f4235114 0x1f4229000 + 49428
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f4237cd4 0x1f4229000 + 60628
```

Anyone knows, what may be the exact reason behind this.
I execute my application approximat 30-40 times and it crashed only one time and I am unable to Identify the exact reason behind it.

Comment: What does an error occur when you run it? Please show me the code where the error occurred.

Comment: Error is not producing every time.
Random crash occurred only with release app.

Comment: I am getting the exact same crash. In my case it is more frequent - say 1 out of three runs. My guess is that it is an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 2):

It can be "react-native-wheel-picker-android" package. 
I have same issue, in my case, app crashing with "selectedItemTextColor" prop. 
Here is issue in GitHub repo page: https://github.com/Cero-Studio/ReactNativeWheelPicker/issues/123

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer by any stretch of the imagination, but I have installed a global exception handler to help me find the actual culprit.

To install global exception handlers (JS and Native) check out:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exception-handler